Browser displays small image but downloaded correct, bigger one
I have simple code for handling responsive images dependent on device (image urls may don't work as they are in company network but it does not matter.):
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 769px)" srcset="https://publish-p138454-e1492404.adobeaemcloud.com/content/dam/image-renditions-test/Cloud.png/_jcr_content/renditions/1x2horizontalwebpx1.webp 1x, https://publish-p138454-e1492404.adobeaemcloud.com/content/dam/image-renditions-test/Cloud.png/_jcr_content/renditions/1x2horizontalwebpx2.webp 2x">
    <source media="(max-width: 768px)" srcset="https://publish-p138454-e1492404.adobeaemcloud.com/content/dam/image-renditions-test/Cloud.png/_jcr_content/renditions/1x2horizontalwebpx1.webp 1x, https://publish-p138454-e1492404.adobeaemcloud.com/content/dam/image-renditions-test/Cloud.png/_jcr_content/renditions/1x2horizontalwebpx2.webp 2x, https://publish-p138454-e1492404.adobeaemcloud.com/content/dam/image-renditions-test/Cloud.png/_jcr_content/renditions/1x2horizontalwebpx3.webp 3x">
    <img src="placeholder.webp" style="aspect-ratio: 4 / 3; border-radius: 0px; max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; object-fit: contain;">
</picture>

For mobile phones it has 3 different image sizes, for desktop 2 different image sizes.
It looks in the network section that browser loads always the correct one, for example for iPhone it loads only x3 for retina so thats great.
But it displays always the x1 size even if in network there is no request for x1. I tried to remove all styles from <img but it did not help. How browser know that such image exists before loading it? Why browser displays image x1 (or scaled x3 to x1 size) instead of x3? Is it some browser strange mechanism?
I use Edge with MacOS


Please add a [mcve] to your quesion.
